# How to enable .htaccess in AWS Lightsail LAMP module

Tags: amazon-web-services, .htaccess, web-hosting, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I am new to AWS Lightsail.

I have successfully migrated my web application to a LAMP server (bitnami) and I generated SSL certificate. now I want to redirect to HTTP to HTTPS. Hence I created `.htaccess` and copied the below the code and restarted my server. but the **page is not** migrating from http to https. can you please help me to enable `.htaccess`?

Since I am planning to host 3 websites, I am looking for `.htaccess` so that I can configure locally based on the condition.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.in [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.test.in/$1 [R,L]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here:

By default, we disable .htaccess files due to security and performance reasons. We also move .htaccess files content to a file called `htaccess.conf` in the folder /opt/bitnami/apps/APPNAME/conf. You can check more about it at https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/lamp/administration/use-htaccess/.

If you want to enable .htaccess usage, you would need to set it to *AllowOverride All* in `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All <---- HERE
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3 >
      Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
  </Directory>
```

Restart Apache after applying your changes.

Regards

Comment: i tried `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf` and tells me `Permission denied` in my case I need to enable compression, gzip and expiring headers etc and I need to modify `htaccess`

Comment: `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf` was already to set to AllowOverride All for me. I needed to update it `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf` as well.

Comment: This helped me to setup Rewrite rule in order to enable JWT authentication for WordPress.

Comment: At least for a wordpress setup, the file you need to modify and its location has changed. As of Dec 2021, the location of file you need to edit is at `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/vhosts/wordpress-https-vhost.conf`

Comment: @Wesley - Dont know how you found this, but as of 10-9-2023 this is still the correct file and location. Thank you

Comment: @BoundForGlory – I don't remember, but I'm sure God showed me. I'm bound for glory too by His grace.

Comment: @Wesley - I wasn't expecting that answer. You truly blessed me. God bless you too :)

Answer (score 2):

- Open Terminal
- type ls (you'll see a list of directories & files)
- type cd apps/wordpress/conf
- type ls
- type nano htaccess.conf

htaccess file will open.
edit it as per your requirements and press ctrl + x to exit
be sure to press y to save the changes.
reboot the lightsail instance.
done.

Answer (score 0):

if you've done configuring the SSL configuration then add the redirect option on your vhost file which you must have created for the website to view online.

Whatever modification you do to your server please make sure to create back up and always try to create new modification files. So you could use the **redirect** option on you app's virtual host file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName your_domain_name.com
    ServerAlias www.your_domain_name.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.your_domain_name.com/
    DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs 
    <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs">
          Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
      AllowOverride All 
      Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope this works for you.